# How would I detect superscript for one word if there's no parentheses, but if there are parentheses, for all the contents of them?

Tags: regex

I want to detect the two following circumstances, preferably with one regex:

> This is a sentence **^that** I wrote today.

And:

> This is a sentence **^(that I wrote)** today.

So basically, if there are parentheses after the caret, I want to match whatever is inside them.  Otherwise, I just want to match just the next word.

I'm new to regex. Is this possible without making it too complicated?

Comment: I think this should do it for you `\^(\w+|\([^)]+\))`

Comment: @CrayonViolent Could you explain that?

Comment: looks for a literal `^` followed by **either** 1 or more word chars `\w+` **or** literal open paren followed by one or more non-closing paren followed by literal closing paren

Comment: @DougSmith: What should happen in the case of cascading brackets: For instance **^(that (I) wrote)**?? If this should match the entire boldface part, it can't be done with a regex... It's a concequence of the *pumping lemma for regular languages*...

Comment: it is possible to ignore nested parens but it does increase the complexity of the regex (what i posted originally doesn't account for that)

Comment: @CrayonViolent: It’s not possible to ignore arbitrarily nested parentheses (without engine-specific extensions).

Answer (score 1):

```
\^(\w+|\([\w ]+\))

Options: case insensitive; ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the character “^” literally «\^»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+|\([\w ]+\))»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\w+»
      Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «\w+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\([\w ]+\)»
      Match the character “(” literally «\(»
      Match a single character present in the list below «[\w ]+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
         A word character (letters, digits, etc.) «\w»
         The character “ ” « »
      Match the character “)” literally «\)»


Created with RegexBuddy
```